# Optimal design for PWM parameters in Simulink

Tags: simulink

I am simulating a simple open loop 3 phase inverter with a inductive filter and resistive load, using a PWM block to drive the gates. Model is using the following:

[image]

Inductive Filter : 10mH

Resistive Load : 5 Ohm

DC Voltage : 50 V

Fixed step solver sampling time : 1e-6

PWM Switching Frequency : 10kHz

These is excessive noise in the output current. This becomes a problem when I try implement some closed loop controllers. I do not want to add in a capacitor due to the controller I am using.

[image]

Adjusting the switching frequency to 20 kHz has no improvement, reducing it to 1 kHz increases the amplitude of the noise.

I realise this noise is contributed by the switches, but the amplitude of it feels way too much.

Is there an optimal design for PWM to reduce this noise ?

Comment: The problem is not possible to resolve without the good design specs to be added for complex impedances during switching.  Specs such as component capacitance charge vs voltage and reverse recovery times, path inductance and loop mutual coupling later become important.  FoM's include Rg*Ciss RdsOn*Coss and Cdg*Rg and Coss*L

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Thanks for the comment. Can you please provide a reference to what FoM's are. Do you know a textbook I can learn this stuff from ?

Comment: no but you can search **figure of merit** in a Socratic method  https://www.google.com/search?q=figure+of+merit+fet+design&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALiCzsZF2N4WwuJwrISIqKVYOYSfnPITAw%3A1671275250444&ei=8qKdY6_aGs-0qtsP8d6k4A8&ved=0ahUKEwivm_-8wYD8AhVPmmoFHXEvCfwQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=figure+of+merit+fet+design&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIHCCEQoAEQCjoKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzoHCAAQsAMQQzoECAAQQzoGCAAQBxAeOgUIABCABDoGCAAQFhAeOgUIABCGAzoICAAQHhAPEA06CwgAEAgQHhDxBBANOggIABAIEB4QDToICCEQFhAeEB06CgghEBYQHhAPEB1KBAhBGABKBAhGGABQ9gtY01Jg-1hoAXABeACAAYcBiAHrCpIBAzQuOZgBAKABAcgBCsABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-serp

Comment: https://eepower.com/technical-articles/rethinking-the-power-mosfet-figure-of-merit/#

Comment: Thanks @TonyStewartEE75